# Making Safari work with my iframe-based Facebook app

Tags: safari, facebook

I see a lot of references to my problem, but none to a solution.  I hope someone can help.

I have an iframe-based canvas Facebook app, which uses Javascript SDK for authentication and Python on the back end.  Now, my understanding is that Safari does not allow 3rd party iframes to set cookies.  But then how do I make links in my iframe-based canvas app work?  Of course I can start appending signed_request parameter to each link, but this sounds very ugly.

I've looked at the sample Facebook app "runwithfriends" (https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends), which seems to have solved this problem.  They don't have any links, but they have a button "Add Run" which does work.  I'd love to be able to figure out how they do it without having to go to Google app engine to actually debug it (I don't use Google app engine now).

Any ideas?

Many thanks and happy new year to everyone,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Apparently, it IS possible to set a cookie from a 3rd party iframe for Safari, but only from a POST request.  This is what the sample app does - it sets its own cookie instead of relying on Facebook SDK's cookie.  It works.